# The payoff in binomial model is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, finance

Let $V_N$ the payoff of a security at time $N$, recurssvely define
\begin{equation}
V_n=\frac{1}{r+1}(\tilde{p}V_{n+1}(H)+\tilde{q}V_{n+1}(T))
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{q},\tilde{p}$ are the risk free probabilities. I am trying to prove that $V_n$ is a martingale, what I was doing is given a sequence of results  $(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)$ of $H,T$, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
V_n(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)&=\frac{1}{r+1}(\tilde{p}V_{n+1}(\omega_1,...,\omega_n,H)+\tilde{q}V_{n+1}(\omega_1,...,\omega_n,T))\\
&=\frac{1}{1+r}\tilde{\mathbb{E}}(V_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ is the information given by $(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)$, but this means that is not a martingale, so I don't know what I am  wrong, or what is my mistake?

Comment: Does the post below answer your question? If so, please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. However, it is not the payoff process that should be a martingale, but rather the **discounted** payoff process. This is what you have shown in your calculation.